# EF generated query performance tuning required. Or a database issue?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, sqlperformance

I have a search query generated by EF 6 which **sometimes** causing performance issue for the search criteria which yields large results. The query performance is unpredictable, sometimes it performs good and sometimes its not.The following is the query caught in sql profiler, which queries a view

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
.
. 
FROM (SELECT 
[PersonView].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[PersonView].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
.
.
FROM [Staff].[PersonView] AS [PersonView]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[FirstName] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0  varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='smith'
```

Following is the repository code

```
public IEnumerable<PersonSearchResult> SearchPersons(Expression<Func<PersonView, bool>> searchCriteria)
{
    var query = _entities.PersonViews.AsExpandable().Where(searchCriteria);
    return query;
}
```

I'm using the predicate builder to create dynamic search criteria.

**My concern is with the unpredictable nature of the performance with the same search criteria.**

Following are my questions

1. I believe the Select x from select x from table query format is causing this issue. When I executed just the inner part of the Select then it was performing better when whole query was struggling. Does this need tuning? If yes, where to start with?
2. Or Is this an issue with the database? Because this query performs well sometimes?

Comment: You need to see if performance issues are correlated with filters on particular columns. You need to do more analysis.

Comment: Run the query in SSMS, check the execution plan, there might be suggested indexes there.

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. Depending on the actual set of conditions in the `WHERE` part, SQL Server might utilise indices, which will result in much better performance (assuming there are any). Filtering by non-indexed columns is slow and resource consuming, but worst of all - it is unpredictably slow, i.e. tolerable today and stalling tomorrow.

Usually, columns with lengthy text such as persons' names are rarely indexed, so your particular example is destined to perform poorly. Unless, of course, search by first / last names is a crucial part of your system functionality and you will create indices for all columns that might be mentioned in search criteria, including as large as these ones.

I would recommend searching for SQL scripts that show "suggested indexes", should be handy.